# AngularJS + Jasmine .then statements in unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

So I have below an excerpt from my unit tests. The following runs normally, but the console.log statement does not occur. Furthermore, the console.log statement in the service does not occur either. I have tried adding a .error bit to the end of it, but that makes absolutely no difference. I want to get my LoginService.refreshToken().then function to work properly.

```
it('refreshToken Executes Properly', inject(function (LoginService, $httpBackend, localStorageService) {
    var dummyToken = {""};
    localStorageService.set('token', dummyToken);
    $httpBackend.expect('POST', 'URL', data2, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "",
                    "Accept": "",
    "Authorization": ""
                }
            }).respond(200, {success:true});
    //nothing inside the below function does anything??
    LoginService.refreshToken().then(function(response) {
        console.log("Ran");
        expect(response.data.success).toBe(true);
    });
}));
```

Here is my service

```
refreshToken: function(refreshCallback) {
        var baseURL = sharedProperties.getBaseURL();
        var token = localStorageService.get('token');
        if (token && token.refresh_token) {
            var data = "";
            return $http.post(URL, data, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "",
                    "Accept": "",
                    "Authorization": "")
                }
            }).success(function(response) {
                var expiredAt = new Date();
                console.log("Attempt A");
                expiredAt.setSeconds(expiredAt.getSeconds() + response.expires_in);
                response.expires_at = expiredAt.getTime();
                localStorageService.set('token', response);
                if (refreshCallback) {
                    refreshCallback();
                }
                return response;
            });
        }
    }
```

I originally thought that my if statement was not being satisfied, but I checked and that is not the case. Something is simply not working correctly and I have no idea what. I have a function that is nearly identical, as well as a test, which DOES do what I want in terms of having a working .then statement. I've posted it below. I do not understand what is so different about my two functions that one of them works and the other does not.

```
initiateRequest: function (username, password) {   
        var baseURL = sharedProperties.getBaseURL();
        var data = ""; 
        $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = '';
        $http.defaults.headers.post['Accept'] = '';
        $http.defaults.headers.post['Authorization'] = "";
        return $http.post(URL, data, {}).success(function(response) {
            var expiredAt = new Date();
            expiredAt.setSeconds(expiredAt.getSeconds() + response.expires_in);
            response.expires_at = expiredAt.getTime();
            localStorageService.set('token', response);
            $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = undefined;
            $http.defaults.headers.post['Accept'] = undefined;
            $http.defaults.headers.post['Authorization'] = undefined;
            return response;
        })



it('Login Execute Properly', inject(function (LoginService, $httpBackend, localStorageService) {
    $httpBackend.expect('POST', URL, data, {
    "Content-Type": "",
    "Accept": "",
    "Authorization": ""
    }).respond(200, {success: true});
    LoginService.initiateRequest("", "").then(function(response) {
        expect(response.data.success).toBe(true);
        testToken = response;
    });
    var testToken = localStorageService.get('token');
    $httpBackend.flush();
}));
```

Comment: `var dummyToken = {""};`: that's not valid JavaScript.

Comment: I realize that, I've removed sensitive code for privacy reasons. The dummyToken variable is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run **$rootScope.$apply** in your unit test to tell the test runner to resolve (e.i. apply) all promises.